# Is byte-compiling Python platform-specific?

Tags: python, bytecode

I want to byte-compile a python library I use on an embedded device.

Basically, I want to preprocess all `*.py` files to `__pycache__/*.pyc` files to avoid that happening the first time this app is used and slowing everything down.

I'm trying to understand if this pre bytecode-translation step has any dependency on the place in which it run (my laptop vs another device).
  If I byte-compile my python app with [compileall](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/compileall.html) on an Ubuntu box (x86-based) and then take those bytecode-translated files that get placed in a `__pycache__` directory to an embedded linux box (ARM-based), will they work?  Is byte-compiling platform specific?

I'm less concerned about whether `.pyc` files are compatible with different versions of python as much as different underlying architectures.  Both my machine and the device use python3.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the limitations of distributing .pyc files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368304/what-are-the-limitations-of-distributing-pyc-files)

Comment: That question's a perfect duplicate. I wish it had better answers...

Comment: I'm sure we have something better in the corpus somewhere; I've seen a question on the topic with an answer that was downright canonical, but am having trouble finding it now.

Comment: (For those curious, see also the excellent answer to not-as-close-a-duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263356/are-python-2-5-pyc-files-compatible-with-python-2-6-pyc-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I byte-compile my python app [...] on an Ubuntu box (x86-based) and then take those bytecode-translated files [...] to an embedded linux box (ARM-based), will they work?

Assuming that the interpreter version uses a compatible bytecode form (only changed when major or minor version numbers differ), yes, they will work.

Quoting from [an excellent answer to a related question by John La Rooy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2263375/14122):

> ```
> # python:  file(1) magic for python
> 0   string      """ a python script text executable
> 0   belong      0x994e0d0a  python 1.5/1.6 byte-compiled
> 0   belong      0x87c60d0a  python 2.0 byte-compiled
> 0   belong      0x2aeb0d0a  python 2.1 byte-compiled
> 0   belong      0x2ded0d0a  python 2.2 byte-compiled
> 0   belong      0x3bf20d0a  python 2.3 byte-compiled
> 0   belong      0x6df20d0a  python 2.4 byte-compiled
> 0   belong      0xb3f20d0a  python 2.5 byte-compiled
> 0   belong      0xd1f20d0a  python 2.6 byte-compiled
> ```

...if your platforms use a compatible enough version to share the same magic, the .pyc files will work between them.

Comment: Useful for discovering .pyc bytecode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807541/is-there-a-way-to-know-by-which-python-version-the-pyc-file-was-compiled